# gtk.css gtk3 blurred image button

Tags: css, themes, gtk3

I am trying to port an gtk2 theme to gtk3, but i've encountered a problem while doing this. 
Using construction

```
radio {
    background-color: transparent;
    -gtk-icon-source: url("../assets/radio.png");
    -xfce-smooth-edge: false; 
}
radio:checked {
    animation: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -gtk-icon-source: url("../assets/radio-pressed.png");
}
```

Gives me non-sharp image edges as i've shown below.

[Correct gtk2 rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOANM.jpg)

[Incorrect gtk3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqhTC.jpg)

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, both of those images looked blurred to me.

Comment: Please try to focus only on button edges. On first screenshot you can injure yourself while touchnig outer side of radiobutton because edges are sharp; revelant button on second ss is blurred, antialiased.And that's what i am trying to acheive- sharp, dangerous edges :D